# When I use @Transactional annotation many-to-one relations come null

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

When I use @Transactional, after I save objects, hibernate get function returns object which join fields are null.

This is my business layer. @Transactional annotation is there.

```
@Override
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public KonKonfigCoverView addWithNewObj(KonKonfigCoverView objView, Long kurumId)
        throws MosBaseException {

    EnvanterKitTanimView kitView = null;

    if (objView.getKit() != null){
        kitView = objView.getKit();
        if ("0001".equals(kitView.getEnvanterKitTip().getKod())){ //ATS
            kitView = atsKitBO.addObj(kitView, kurumId);
        }
        else if("0002".equals(kitView.getEnvanterKitTip().getKod())){ //OGSHGS
            kitView = ogsHgsBO.addObj(kitView, kurumId);
        }
        else if("0004".equals(kitView.getEnvanterKitTip().getKod())){ //TTS
            kitView = akaryakitKitBO.addObj(kitView, kurumId);
        }
        objView.getKonKonfig().setKit(kitView);
        objView.getKonKonfigDegisiklikDetay().setKit(kitView);
        objView.setKit(kitView);
    }

    KonKonfigCoverView view = this.addObj(objView, kurumId);

    if (objView.getKit() != null){
        view.setKit(kitView);
    }
    return view;
}
```

This is the this.addObj function:

```
@Override
public KonKonfigView addObj(KonKonfigView view, Long kurumId) throws MosBaseException{

    KonKonfig addedObj = konKonfigDAO.addObj(beforeAddObj, ilkTakilmaOdo, sonTakilmaOdo);
    addedObj= konKonfigDAO.getObj(addedObj.getId());

    return (KonKonfigView) BaseHelper.gulmekYok(KonKonfig.class, KonKonfigView.class, addedObj, true, EnViewTip.FULL_DESCRIPTION, null);
}
```

This add operation works well, however getObj function returns object that many-to-one relation fields are null.

One of my fields which comes null is that:

```
@ManyToOne(optional=true)
@JoinColumn(name="CAR_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private Car car;
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are saving the car object before you save the enclosing object, then the field will definitely be null. Hibernate sets the cascade type for a `@ManyToOne` mapping to none.

This means that operations that were done on the enclosing object will not be done to the objects mapped inside unless you specify a specific cascade type.

You can do the following to solve this problem:

```
Option 1: @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)

Option 2: 
@ManyToOne
@Cascade(CascadeType.PERSIST)
```

Checkout the different [CascadeTypes](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/metamodel/binding/CascadeType.html) so you can choose the right one for what you need.

Comment: It did not solve the problem.I think the reason is that I don't save car object. I just assign a car id to enclosing object at front end. I have two fields for car object. `@ManyToOne(optional=true) @JoinColumn(name="CAR_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false) private Car car; @Column(name="CAR_ID") private Long carId;` When I save my enclosing object I save it with **carId** field which contains id of one of car objects and then I get back my enclosing object. It brings **car** object also unless I used @Transactional annotation. If I used @Transactional car object comes null.